# "Paused in Debugger" every single time I open the chrome console, even with all breakpoints disabled

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, console

Every single time I open the chrome console via right click + inspect, it swaps the tab to the Sources tab and greys out the screen while throwing up the "Paused in debugger" message. I have been trying to fix this for a bit now, but to no avail.

I have disabled all breakpoints.

I have made sure that all the symbols are blacked out. I even tried enabling the arrow-like sign that says deactivate breakpoints, but that doesn't stick.

I'm a bit lost considering the fix that worked for literally everyone else has not worked for me. Any help is appreciated, and I apologize if this is some super simple stuff that I have missed.

[Here's an image of what my Sources sidebar looks like at the moment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bYVq.png)